# Equivalent command for --upgradable in apt-get

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Ubuntu prints out: To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

So I try

```
$ apt list --upgradable > list.txt
```

, to redirect to a file, but it complains:

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in
> scripts.

So I replace `apt` with `apt-get`

```
$ apt-get list --upgradable > list.txt
```

But I get the error:

> E: Command line option --upgradable is not understood in combination
> with the other options

SO what command should I use to place the upgradable list in a file?

**EDIT**
My Ubuntu version is  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: At least in 18.04 there is no `list` option in `apt-get`

Comment: `apt list --upgradable > list.txt` works and writes to `list.text`, a warning is not an error. You may want to redirect stderr to suppress the warning: `apt list --upgradable > list.txt 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @mook765 No it did not for me, did you try it yourself? My list.txt file was empty / 0 size.

Comment: Hmm. When I tried it, there was plenty of output saved to a test file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in Ubuntu 18.04 it's

`apt-get --just-print upgrade`

which gives, for example

```
me@mypc:~$  apt-get --just-print upgrade
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-libc-dev systemd
  systemd-sysv udev
9 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Inst libnss-systemd [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libsystemd0 [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [systemd:amd64 ]
Conf libsystemd0 (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [systemd:amd64 ]
Inst libpam-systemd [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) [systemd:amd64 ]
Inst systemd [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst udev [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst libudev1 [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libudev1 (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf systemd (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst systemd-sysv [237-3ubuntu10.45] (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst google-chrome-stable [89.0.4389.128-1] (90.0.4430.72-1 Google:1.0/stable [amd64])
Inst linux-libc-dev [4.15.0-141.145] (4.15.0-142.146 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
Conf libnss-systemd (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf libpam-systemd (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf udev (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf systemd-sysv (237-3ubuntu10.46 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf google-chrome-stable (90.0.4430.72-1 Google:1.0/stable [amd64])
Conf linux-libc-dev (4.15.0-142.146 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64])
```

If you use `sudo` some of the warnings go away.

Comment: `$ apt-get --just-print upgrade > list.txt ` and I am done, cheers. No wonder I still love Windows + Microsoft :-)

Comment: same command works in 16.04 as well.