# how to list all upgradable packages without using apt

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I have a script like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

apt-get update

[ "$(apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | grep -c upgradable)" -gt 0 ] &&
apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs -y &&
apt-get autoremove -y &&
apt-get autoclean -y
```

only problem is that everytime I run this, it shows warning about `apt` not having a stable cli. How can I list all upgradable packages without `apt`?
On `apt` manpage it says that `apt list` is similar to `dpkg-query`, but I could not find a way to list upgradable packages using `dpkg-query`.

edit: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using? `apt` does have a stable cli in the recent versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent command for --upgradable in apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332550/equivalent-command-for-upgradable-in-apt-get) Short answer - Use `apt-get --just-print upgrade` instead of `apt list --upgradable`).